# showing a polynomial does not factor in Z[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that $f(x) = x^5 + x^2 + 1$ does not factor in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as a product of lower degree polynomials. prof did it in class but did not fully explain: he just wrote that it is enough to show that there is a prime $p$ such that the reduction of $f(x)$ modulo prime $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Im trying to understand how this gives the proof the our problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can factor it in $\mathbb Z$ then you can also factor it in $\mathbb Z_p$, just write the factorization in $\mathbb Z_p$ and reduce every coefficient $\bmod p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You prove this by contrapositive: if $f(x)$ is reducible in $\mathbf Z[x]$, then it is reducible in $\mathbf F_p[x]$ for all primes $p$. This works because, as $f(x)$ is monic, it does not reduce to $0$ modulo $p$.

Comment: Why is $f(x)$ monic?

Comment: This means its leading coefficient is $1$ (it might as well be a unit in any P.I.D.).